# Как найти число в массиве JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Допустим есть некий массив `['r', 'b', '2', 'd']`, понятно что в данном случае цифра = строка, в том и суть, как прогнать массив так, чтобы он нашел цифру и вернул true или false если не нашел?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isNaN` сработает как и с `'2'`, так `2`. Можно использовать его с `map()` и получить данные для всего массива:

```
['r', 'b', '2', 'd'].map(value => { return !isNaN(value); })
```

Answer (score 1):

Давай по порядку. Сначала перебираем массив(допустим с помощью метода forEach).

```
const arr = ['r', 'b', '2', 'd'];
arr.forEach(item => {
   .......
})
```

Теперь нам надо написать функционал, который поймёт число ли это

```
function isNumber(n) {
    ........
}
```

Чтобы узнать тип, можем использовать `typeof`. Но проблема в том, что `typeof '5'` вернёт string.
Можем использовать конструктор `Number(item)` . Тогда число трансформируется в число('5' => 5), а строка в NaN('a' => NaN).
В JS есть функция `isNaN()` результат которой мы будем возвращать. Итоговый код будет выглядеть так:

```
const arr = ['r', 'b', '2', 'd'];

arr.forEach(item => {
   isNumber(item);
})

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(Number(n));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = ['r', 'b', '2', 'd', '0']

console.log(a.filter(x => x == +x))
console.log(a.find(x => x == +x))
console.log(+a.find(x => x == +x))
```

Answer (score 0):

преобразуйте строки в цифры, если ошибка то не цифра

Comment: Тогда возвращает NaN с не числом, что по типу также нумбер

Comment: @Jaroslaw тогда сраниваете если не NaN то ок если NaN то не цифра

Answer (score 0):

**вариант 1:**

```
let arr = ['r', 'b', '2', 'd']
const res = arr.filter(elem => elem.localeCompare(String(+elem)) == 0).length != 0
```

**вариант 2:**

```
let arr = ['r', 'b', '2', 'd']
const res = arr.some(elem => elem.localeCompare(String(+elem)) == 0)
```

проверку на число можно сделать и потяжелее:

```
function isNumeric(str) {
    if (typeof str != "string") return false
    return !isNaN(str) && !isNaN(parseFloat(str))
}
```

Comment: ````locale````???

Comment: @Qwertiy из строки в число и обратно и проверил что строки совпадают, но лучше `isNumber`

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

```
const arr = ['r', 'b', '2', 'd']
const number = 2
const isTrue = arr.includes(number+'')
// true
console.log(isTrue)
```

Comment: если цифра может быть еще и числом, а не только строкой то:


const isTrue = arr.includes(number+'') || arr.includes(number)